# Why are my results for a Chi-Squared-test wildly different from the results of logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

thank you for taking the time to read my question. So, I have the following issue: I am trying to establish whether or not two categorical variables are associated (according to what we know, they really should be). At first, I used a Chi-Squared-test; however, the subjects are clustered and the ICC is 0.15, so I decided to use a mixed logistic regression. However, I did not even get that far, because simply trying to establish the same association as in the Chi-Squared-test produced a completely different result. My data look like this:

```
'data.frame':   322 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 7 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 7 1 2 4 4 3 5 5 7 3 ...
 $ V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "yes","sometimes",..: 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ G : Factor w/ 23 levels "13",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

V1 and V2 are the variables of interest, G is the grouping variable, which I'll ignore for now. I then first calculated the Chi-Squared-test:

```
    > vdat3a <- vdat3[c("V1", "V2")]
    > vdat3b <- table(vdat3a)
    > chisq.test(vdat3b)
    
        Pearson's Chi-squared test
    
    data:  vdat3b
    X-squared = 36.29, df = 12, p-value = 0.0002909
    
    Warning message:
    In chisq.test(vdat3b) : Chi-Quadrat-Approximation kann inkorrekt sein 
[Chi-Square Approximation may be incorrect, my translation - what does this tell me here?]
    > library(rcompanion)
    > cramerV(vdat3b)
    Cramer V 
      0.2412
```

Now, in order to (eventually) account for the clusters, I tried to do the same thing as a logistic regression:

```
> log_model <- glm(formula = V1 ~ V2, data = vdat3, family = binomial)
> log_model

Call:  glm(formula = V1 ~ V2, family = binomial, data = vdat3)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  V2sometimes         V2no  
     1.4104      -0.2934      -0.3988  

Degrees of Freedom: 311 Total (i.e. Null);  309 Residual
  (10 Beobachtungen als fehlend gelöscht)
Null Deviance:      324.6 
Residual Deviance: 323.3    AIC: 329.3
> 
> modelChi <- log_model$null.deviance - log_model$deviance
> modelChi
[1] 1.315789
> chidf <- log_model$df.null - log_model$df.residual
> chidf
[1] 2
> chisq.prob <- 1 - pchisq(modelChi, chidf)
> chisq.prob
[1] 0.5179407
> R2.hl <- modelChi/log_model$null.deviance
> R2.hl
[1] 0.004053713
```

So no we go from a Chi-Squared-test that was significant with a substantial effect size **(p < 0.01, Cramér's V = 0.24)** to a log regression model that is not significantly different from a model without a predictor **(p = 0.52, R2L < 0.01)** and I just can't make sense of it. Anyone able to help?

Comment: V1 and V2 are categorical variables that both have more than two possible values, so I wouldn't expect logistic regression to give a sensible output here.

Comment: Further to Accidental Statistician's comment, the key issue is that V1, the target variable of your GLM, has no less than 7 levels. In a case like this, a logistic model is not appropriate. I assume `glm` silently converts your V1 into a binary variable (probably using the alphabetically first factor level as 1 and everything else as 0, or the other way around), which of course produces complete nonsense.

Comment: Thank you both - I thought that `glm` would produce multinomial logistic regression in this case? If not - what other method would be appropriate?

Comment: `glm` will never do multinomial logistic regression.  There is a function in package `nnet` that will do it, try that. Name is `multinom`.  As for the warnings in your chisq.test, try ` chisq.test(vdat3b, sim=TRUE)`